# MLlib LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS error when using model.predict

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using MLlib's LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS to train a model with 4 classes.

This is the code for preparing my data,

```
val labeledTraining = trainingSetVectors.map{case(target,features) => LabeledPoint(target,features) }.cache()

val Array(trainingData, testData) = labeledTraining.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
```

Train the model,

```
val model = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
model.setNumClasses(5)
model.run(trainingData)
```

When I try to test the model I get an error

```
val labelAndPreds = testData.map { Labeledpoint =>
  val prediction = model.predict(LabeledPoint.features)
  (LabeledPoint.target, prediction)
}

error: value predict is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS
```

Why is this happening? The model was trained without any errors.

Comment: Because it doesn't. You train and immediately discard the model.  What you call the model is just an algorithm description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"model" is defining what classifier you're going to use.

When you train the model you're not saving it, try this;

```
val classifier = new LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS()
classifier.setNumClasses(5)
val model = classifier.run(trainingData)
```

Comment: FWIW, this mistake is transcribed from directly from the spark docs at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-linear-methods.html